# how to write django inner query sql?

Tags: sql, django

how to write the sql bellow to django model sql language ?

```
select id,author_id from forum_node as answer_node where node_type='answer' and 
'android' in  (select tagnames from forum_node as question_node where
id=answer_node.parent_id );
```

could any one give help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say exactly without seeing you model classes, but selecting the relevant `Forum_Node` objects will look something like this:

```
Forum_Node.objects.filter(
    node_type="answer", 
    parent__tagnames__name__in=['android']
)
```

Or, to get just the `id` and `author_id`:

```
Forum_Node.objects.filter(
    node_type="answer", 
    parent__tagnames__name__in=['android']
).values_list('id', 'author_id')
```

Comment: but , many answer have the same author , how could i get the author list sorted by answer numbers ?

Comment: i fount it is solve my problem , what i want is something like `['android'] in parent__tagnames__name` , but not parent__tagnames__name__in=['android'] .